# Convert webpacked Bundle with map files to original source code (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, webpack, ionic3

I have a Bundled JS project (made with webpack) along with the js.map files that go with. I also have the config that was used for webpack at the moment of the compilation. I want to get back to the original typescript files that gave that bundle.

Is there anyway to reverse the process ? Not necessarily entirely automated but if someone could point me to a direction I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to reverse the process

Yes. Each `.js.map` file contains the source code for each `.ts` file.